# Iterating through multi dimensional array in Go

Tags: go

In the following code example

```
var a [3][5]int8
for _, h := range a {
    for _, cell := range h {
        fmt.Print(cell, " ")
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

is the copy of a row of `a` made in every iteration? i.e., does `h` contain a copy of a row of `a` or does `h` get a reference to it?

Comment: It depends if you're using arrays or a slices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A copy. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a [3][5]int8
    fmt.Println(a)
    for _, h := range a {
        h = [5]int8{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
        for _, cell := range h {
            fmt.Print(cell, " ")
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
    fmt.Println(a)

}
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0]]
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
[[0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [For statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)
>
> A "for" statement with a "range" clause iterates through all entries
>   of an array, slice, string or map, or values received on a channel.
>   For each entry it assigns iteration values to corresponding iteration
>   variables and then executes the block.
>
> The iteration values are assigned to the respective iteration
>   variables as in an assignment statement.

Comment: That's the good answer, but if he's using slices, in the first loop the data itself should not be copied (and it's the same for range on a map).